# Cannot access JSON text file stored in cache

Tags: php, javascript, json, jquery, twitter

I'm having a little trouble with retrieving some JSON data from a field stored in my website's cache. The script I'm writing fetches the latest tweets from a twitter list, stores the JSON data it receives in a .txt file in the cache of the website. This is then read and turned into a string displaying the tweet, or at least it should. I have it working when I don't cache the tweets and just access them directly, but as soon as I try to cache the tweets then access them from cache I'm hitting a wall. The *cache-tweets.php* file is run as a cron job on the server, and works fine, it creates a text file that contains the JSON data no problems. The code for *cache-tweets.php* is below.

```
$cache = dirname(__FILE__) . '/cache/twitter-json.txt';  

$data = file_get_contents('https://api.twitter.com/1/lists/statuses.json?slug=tab&owner_screen_name=swoophoop&per_page=15&page=1&include_entities=true');   

$cachefile = fopen($cache, 'wb');  
fwrite($cachefile,utf8_encode($data));  
fclose($cachefile);
```

This should then be used by this code:

```
<script type ="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function(){
$.ajax({
    dataType: 'json',
    url: 'http://sotontab.co.uk/wp-content/cache/twitter-json.txt',
    success: function (data) {
        var strTweet = '';

        $.each(data, function(index, tweet){                
            var user_link = '\x3Ca href="http://twitter.com/' + tweet.user.screen_name + '">' + '\x3Cb>' + tweet.user.name + '\x3C/b>\x3C/a>';
            strTweet=strTweet + user_link + ' : &nbsp' + tweet.text.linkify() + '&nbsp' + '\x3Cdiv class="time">' + relative_time(tweet.created_at) + '\x3C/div>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp';
        });
        tweetMarquee = new Marquee($('div#marquee'),strTweet,$('div#marquee').width);
    }
});
});      


</script>
```

If I replace the url in the above code with the url from *cahe-tweets.php* it works perfectly and the tweets display inside the marquee on my site. But if I run it as it is, nothing appears. The marquee doesn't even show up as empty. Does anyone know why it doesn't work with the site url as above?

Comment: You have a mistake in your url, though I'm not sure this is your problem, but it should be http not htp

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out, but that isn't the issue, just a typo!

Comment: do you get any Javascript error?

Comment: Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/plain

I've been here far too long, I'd forgotten to even check!

Answer (score 0):

One thing you could try is mark the dataType as text and then do `data = JSON.parse(data);` and sees if it works.  Alternatively it might work if you save the file with a json suffix instead of as a text file.

Comment: This gives XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://sotontab.co.uk/wp-content/cache/twitter-josn.txt Origin is not allowe by Access-Control-Allow-Origin and Unexpected end of input on the JSON.parse

Comment: what is your base url of your site?

Comment: http://sotontab.co.uk but it the code is currently being run on http://test.sotontab.co.uk

Comment: @SamHooper you might try the alternative solution I mentioned, but would be better to have all the files on one domain or the other.

Comment: @qw3n I tried your method, see my first comment for the error messages I received. When the code works it will all be stored and run on sotontab.co.uk, I am only running on test.sotontab.co.uk so the main site can remain live

Comment: @SamHooper I added a second possible way to get it to work, but I think for both options you'll need to have the files on the same domain or in this case the same subdomain.  Try moving the cache file to the test supdomain.

Comment: @qw3n, sorry I missed your edit. Unfortunately no luck, even with the files on the same domain.